# Trying to pass value to a function that has been passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code. If I pass the setText function once to the MyClicker class it works fine. So, in the code below, I see the text "Second Text" show up correctly.

However, I am also wanting to pass the setText function to a grandchild class. The text "3rd Text" below never shows up.

The button shows up fine, however, it does not appear to do anything when I click it. There is no error message displayed in the console and the setText() function is not getting called.

I originally had:

```
<Voo setText={this.setText.bind(this)} />
```

instead of

```
<Voo setText={() => this.setText} />
```

but was getting the following error:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state
>   transition

After looking into the cause of the error, I tried the arrow function as above, but again there is no error, and the setText function does not get invoked.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

Poo Class:

```
import MyClicker from './MyClicker'
import Voo from './Voo'

class Poo extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            text: "Intro Text",
        };

    }

    setText(text){
        this.setState({
            text: text
        })
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{this.state.text}</h2>
                <MyClicker handleClick={this.setText.bind(this, "Second Text")} text="Click for 2nd Text" />

                <Voo setText={() => this.setText} />
        )
    }

}
```

Voo class:

```
import MyClicker from './MyClicker'
class Voo extends React.Component {

    render(){
        <MyClicker handleClick={this.props.setText("Third Text")} text="Click for 3rd Text" />
    }

}
```

MyClicker class:

```
class MyClicker extends React.Component {

    handleClick(){
        this.props.handleClick();
    }


    render(){
        return (
            <div onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.text}</div>
            )

    }

}
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: On your Voo class it should be `handleClick={() => this.props.setText("Third Text")}`. If you use it like you did the function gonna be executed rather than just passing as a prop. parenthesizes executes the function.

Comment: @bennygenel Thank you. That worked. Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: Second error was that you wrote `<Voo setText={() => this.setText} />` instead of `<Voo setText={() => this.setText()} />`.

`() => this.setText()` - you've missed the parentheses after `this.setText`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Voo` class has a small syntax error on `handleClick` prop.

It should be like below;

```
class Voo extends React.Component {
    render(){
        <MyClicker handleClick={() => this.props.setText("Third Text")} text="Click for 3rd Text" />
    }
}
```

If you use it like you did the function gonna be executed rather than just passing as a prop. Parenthesizes executes the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your function like this. And pass the `setText` as below, then you will pass this and what ever needed "automatically".

If you use `()` you will execute `setState`, which will rerender your component and that will execute the state again... an endless loop has been created.

```
setText = (text) => {
  this.setState({
      text: text
  })
}

<Voo setText={this.setText} />
```

Comment: while that is correct, this feature hasn't been fully implemented yet in the current standards.

Comment: Could you address me on what stage this is on? I could not find it.